# Problem with the deletion of row in Jtable when it is highlighted

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Here I have a loop that will get the indexes of rows that has been highlighted in the table when the Delete button is clicked

```
private void jButton5MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    //DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
    int[] row = jTable2.getSelectedRows();
    for (int i =0; i < jTable2.getSelectedRowCount();i++){
        int rows = jTable2.convertRowIndexToModel(row[i]);
        System.out.println("row [" + rows +"]");
    //model.removeRow(rows); 
        
    }
            
}
```

Table Pic:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KffGy.png)

Console Pic: [Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeN2d.png)

however when I added `model.removeRow(rows)` to delete the rows based on the index that it recorded, it doesn't delete it.

Example:

```
private void jButton5MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
    int[] row = jTable2.getSelectedRows();
    for (int i =0; i < jTable2.getSelectedRowCount();i++){
        int rows = jTable2.convertRowIndexToModel(row[i]);
        System.out.println("row [" + rows +"]");
    //added
    model.removeRow(rows); 
        
    }
            
}
```

Table Pic:[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KffGy.png)

Here's the output after the delete button is clicked, it only deleted 2 rows
and the console outputs only 2 indexes instead of 3 indexes

Table After Button Click Pic:[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1QT2.png)

Console Pic: [Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AadTD.png)

The problem might have been

```
model.removeRow(rows);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table. 2) `jButton5MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)` For a button, use an `ActionListener`. It will respond to both mouse ***and*** keyboard input.

Comment: I don't know why you're thanking me given you've implemented *neither* piece of the advice offered.

Comment: Once you use the ActionListener you will still have a problem. Your will delete the wrong row from the model because your indexes will not be correct. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702044/delete-row-from-jtable/29705127#29705127 for a solution.